# Повторное создание и заполнение массива в c++

Tags: c++, память, динамические-массивы

Заполняю массив первый раз - всё работает.
Заполняю повторно не выходя из программы - ошибка при выводе (срабатывает исключение, и пишет, что невозможно прочесть). В чём проблема?

```
cout << "Введите кол-во рейсов" << endl;
cin >> k;
AEROFLOT * n = new AEROFLOT[k];
*n = set(n, k);
while (1)
{
    cout << "1. Ввод информации" << endl;
    cout << "2. Вывод информации по всем рейсам" << endl;
    cout << "0. Выход" << endl;
    cin >> check;           

    switch (check)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        cout << "Введите новое кол-во рейсов" << endl;
        cin >> k;
        delete[] n;
        AEROFLOT * n = new AEROFLOT[k];
        *n = set(n, k);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: и прямо все компилируется?

Comment: Весь код скинуть? Там только вывод

Comment: `AEROFLOT * n` - две декларации, то есть эти два `n` - разные переменные.

Comment: А как мне поступить?! Я думал удалить старый и создать новый, чтобы работала функция вывода

Comment: Уберите `AEROFLOT *` во втором `AEROFLOT * n`.

Comment: Погодите, Вам же уже это рассказывали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805662

Comment: и что вот это за штучка `set(n, k);`?

Comment: 'set(n, k);' - это заполнение.
А насчёт  ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805662, я не понял, что нужно удалять. Сейчас всё работает, спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем же вы удаляете одно, а потом вводите новую переменную с тем же именем и заполняете совсем другое?!

```
   delete[] n;
   AEROFLOT * n = new AEROFLOT[k];
```

Comment: я думал, что при вводе новых "рейсов" лучше всего удалить старый массив, дабы освободить память, создать новый и в него всё записать. Переменную указателя выбрал ту же, чтобы вывод работал как надо.

Comment: А что, нельзя удалить старый массив и создать тот же с тем же именем?

Comment: Уберите `AEROFLOT *` во втором `AEROFLOT * n`

Comment: Удалите. Но заполняйте его же, а не совсем новую переменную. Вы отдаете себе отчет, что `n` в первой строчке и во второй - **разные**? В разных местах в памяти? Не массивы - а сами **переменные** в разных местах? И что когда вы доходите до `break`, то созданный вновь массив просто теряете - получая утечку памяти?

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо, буду знать, что разные переменные